# PHP regex not matching. Online debuggers are finding matches

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match any string in a file that has the following pattern:
'/(!c#[0-9]+)+/' that is "!c#" plus any number. I've got the string "This should close !c#10" which I'm trying to match to. The Regex doesn't match. I'm on PHP 7.3.10

Online PCRE tools all seem to say this should match. However when I run the code on a XAMPP local server it doesn't match. Not using the fgets works.

```php
while (!feof($file)) {
    $pattern = '/(!c#[0-9]+)+/';
    $line = fgets($file);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

In this case the file reads:

```
This should close !c#10
```

I'm expecting the $matches to contain a string of '!c#10'

This returns "array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }"

Comment: Works for me: https://3v4l.org/bjtTR

Comment: It works, https://3v4l.org/fcoqW, so your `fgets` must be causing an issue. Maybe `file_get_contents` or `file()`.

Comment: Note the repeated capturing group is not a good idea to use, use a non-capturing group, `$pattern = '/(?:!c#[0-9]+)+/';`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, there might be another issue then. Like my XAMPP environment. Hopefully someone has dealt with a similar situation before. I'm looking into the fgets and how it might be causing an issue.

Comment: The issue is with the file I'm trying to read from. A git log downloaded from git bash on windows.

Comment: Perhaps show us the file you're trying to load

Comment: @Danon I'm not sure how to upload the file. The issue turned out to be in the encoding of the log file. I was using the command 'git log > gitlog.log' to pull the log. I some how ended up with the encoding: "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line term". I tested the command again and it was encoded in 'ASCII text'. The pattern now returns matches with the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the encoding of my file.

The file was encoded as "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode".

I re-obtained the as "ACSII" and the pattern started to match.

I'm not sure why the original encoding didn't match.